# Disappeared output of banner after updating from d7.31 to d7.32

Tags: 7, upgrading

I have set up a website using mamp. And it has a banner on the front page. I did a back up of files and database before updating. After I updated the core, banner has disappeared from the front page. The rest images, nodes, blocks and views are still in the right place. The view of the banner still exists, block is attached to the same region, images are in the right folders and after creating another banner it did not appear. I checked html and this is where banners supposed to go appears to be empty.

```
<div id="flexslider_views_slideshow_main_banner_slider-block" class="flexslider_views_slideshow_main views_slideshow_main"></div>
```

I do not know what have caused the issue during the upgrading. I can get the previous version from my back up, however, I am interested why did this happen and how can I fixed it without going to my back up. As this not an expected behaviour from drupal.

**Update**

I figured out that after updating the core flex slider module has disappeared and flex slider slideshow view parted from the module, so I had to install both and set up the banner view to flex slider again but now I am facing a different obstacle. The image in my banner is shifted to the right like in the image below.
[image]

I still cannot figure out what makes it shift and how to solve it.

Comment: did you try clearing cache after that, also check the jquery version you are using make it 1.5 or 1.7 also check if there is any DB update and try running the cron once. hope that helps :)

Comment: I have already cleaned cache and was using 1.7 jQuery. I have checked DB I was not sure how to check for a change so I exported the new one and compared the size of the old one 6.8mb and the new one 6.3mb. I have run cron once it did not make an effect. I dropped the new tables from the DB and imported the old ones. No changes in the display of the front page.

Comment: When you updated core did you replace the previous .htaccess file?  I forget that one sometimes.  Or perhaps there was a hack in one of the core modules (bad practice, but sometimes happens).

Comment: I did, are you not supposed to replace .* files?